# How to change Format of a Cell to Text while keeping all data exactly as i see with my eyes-WYSIWYG

Tags: vba, excel, wysiwyg

I want to make a macro that change all cells in my wb to be **text** format. 
in my following code it's change all cells to be text format but the problem with that code is that it's not always "what you see is what you get",
i mean when excel change the format of cells sometimes also change the data inside the cells. 
for example: if I will change cell format from number (decimal place:4) to text, "1.200"  will be in text format "1.2" etc... 
is there any tricky way to change all cells to text format while keeping all data exactly as any user see in his eyes no matter what he see?  (using vba)

VBA:

```
  Cells.Select
  Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
```

Comment: Is it only **numbers** that you need to make WYSIWYG?  If you need to also change text strings so that they are truncated to only be the part that is currently visible at the time you run your code, it starts to get more difficult.  (P.S.  Would it be better to just create a PDF copy of the worksheet?)

Comment: @YowE3K only numbers, I need them to be Text for other use with the wb..
but in the end all cells have to be in text format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim c, v

    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        v = c.Text
        c.NumberFormat = "@"
        c.Value = v
    Next c
End Sub
```

...assuming all content is visible (ie. no columns are too narrow, causing values to show as "########") But then again that *would* be WYSIWYG...